# daemonize rtorrent

Tags: ssh, freebsd, daemon, rtorrent

Just read the man page, but found no option for this. Maybe I missed it, maybe it doesn't exist.
I have a server at home I'm SSHing to for rtorrent, but the torrent stops downloading and won't restart on rtorrent restart, so is there a way I can daemonize so I don't have to sit there and watch it?
(if this is relevant, rtorrent is running on a fresh FreeBSD 9.1 install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rtorrent does not have the ability to daemonise itself. But you can use an
additional tool for that. For example dtach, screen or tmux. Here is an
example of how to create an rtorrent session in tmux.

```
tmux new-session -s rtorrent -d rtorrent
```

This creates a session named “rtorrent”, starts the torrent client and
detaches. You can now log out and rtorrent keeps running. Next time you log in,
you can reattach to the session and bring rtorrent to the foreground using

```
tmux attach-session -t rtorrent
```

Comment: ok, it takes the command, but doesn't let me see any trace of the rtorrent menu, which I need to start anything. How do I fix this?

Comment: oh sorry nevermind

Answer (score 7):

You can run `rtorrent` in a `screen` or `tmux` session so that it will continue running even after you've disconnected.

The apps `screen` and `tmux` are terminal multiplexers which allow you to leave long running terminal tasks alone so that they can run uninterrupted.

#### Example

You can use `screen` for example, like so:

```
$ screen -S rtor_sess
```

This will give you a `screen` session named `rtor_sess`. From within it you can now run your `rtorrent` tasks, when you're done starting them up or checking in on them you can disconnect from the `screen` session with the key combination <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Remember: (Attention + Disconnect).

After some time has passed and you want to peek in on your rtorrent task, you can SSH back into the system where you're screen session was started and do the following commands to see your sessions:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    1506.bp (Detached)
    2335.rtorr_sess (Detached)
    32090.dl    (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

Here you can see that I have 3 sessions. So let's reconnect to our `rtorr_sess` session:

```
$ screen -r rtorr_sess
```

Again to disconnect use the same key combination we used before to disconnect. When you're done you simply exit out of the session to destroy it.